# Terminal multiple file count exclusion based on character in file names

Tags: macos, bash, sorting, terminal

I'm a fairly novice terminal user, and I would like to know how to make a script select files based on a specific character in their names so that it will exclude them from a check of how many files there are in a single folder, which must be displayed as a single number. The character in question is º.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works no matter what the filenames contain:

```
count="$(find . -mindepth 1 -not -name '*º*' -exec printf x \; | wc -c)"
```

Test:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)"
$ touch aº
$ touch b
$ find . -mindepth 1 -not -name '*º*' -exec printf x \; | wc -c
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use filename expansion, also known as globbing:

```
echo *[!w]*
```

will display a list of all the filenames in the current directory that do not include a `w`.

The `*` means "zero or more of any characters"

The `[! ]` contains a list of single characters to exclude

To get a count:

```
for fname in *[!w]*
do
    (( count++ ))
done

echo "$count files without a 'w'"
```

I chose 'w' because it is a little easier to see and test.  There are many other ways this could be done, including `set`, using an array, and the `wc` program.